# Storing Password in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, database-connection, connection-string

I have an SSIS Package which is used to connect Oracle.  I used the Oracle Provider for OLEDB connection manager in SSIS. I have specified my server name, user name and password, selected the check box "Allow Saving Password".  It is running fine on my machine but when I give a copy to another developer, he fails to run as he gets null password error.  Is there a way to save password in SSIS Package so that we don't need to worry about that?

Comment: Click in the background of the package and create a variable, OraclePassword of type string, and type the password. Click once on the Oracle Connection Manager and hit F4 (properties). Find Expressions and click the ellipses (...). In the drop down, find the Password. In the other column, reference the variable you created, `@[User::OraclePassword]`

Answer (score 6):

Your goal is the `Package Protection Level`. By default, it is set to `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`. This means, that all passwords are encrypted using the authors Windows Account. As soon as another user tries to load the package, the passwords will be lost.

There are some other options for this package property. One option would be to use `EncryptSensitiveWithPassword` or `EncryptAllWithPassword`. Using these options, anyone can open an run the package as long as he/she has the password.

Yet another option would be to use the option `DontSaveSensitive`. You will then use the Expressions of the Oracle Connectionmanager to overwrite either the password or the full connection string. I can confirm that this is working pretty fine, we are using this method for our Oracle passwords for years. As this option results in having the password saved on your system(s) unencrypted, you need to be sure to secure it in some other way.

Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141747.aspx

Comment: I tried with EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and EncryptAllWithPassword but they still got the same issue. SSIS didn't retain the password.  Also, FYI, I have a Windows Application which runs SSIS package (due to this package running is just part of a number of steps in our process).  I can't host this on Server and run it.  Can you please advise what do you mean by Oracle connection manager expressions?

Comment: never mind, I created a Variable with my Oracle connection string; Set ConnectionString property to this variable through Expressions.  But, it says Data Source name is too long.  An example of my connection string variable is --- Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myserver)(PORT = myport))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=myservice)));User ID=username;Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=True;Password=password;"

Comment: I don't know about SSIS variable limits, but you can also skip the variables and enter the String directly into the Connection String Expression property. As for the ConnectionString itself, it looks like ours, with the exceptions we use an Oracle TNS-Name instead of its full resolution, therefore it is much shorter.

Comment: The limit to an SSIS string variable under expressions is 4k

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize XML configuration files to store the passwords, but since they are stored in clear text, additional safety measures would be advised to protect the files from prying eyes.

[This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/runeetv/archive/2009/12/22/ssis-package-using-sql-authentication-and-dontsavesensitive-as-protectionlevel.aspx) illustrates how to add and utilize configuration files very nicely.